# Inserting a page break into an SSRS report with columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS that contains 4 Tablix Elements. Since the Tablixes are fairly narrow, I can fit two columns of Tablixes on any page, which I've done using the "Columns" setting underneath the Report properties.

Since the first Tablix is the one with by far the most rows, I would like to separate it from the other Tablixes, i.e. I want the first Tablix to take as many pages as it needs, then have a page break, then have all the other Tablixes (which happen to fit on one page). I don't care so much about the report output, but rather the PDF export.

I've tried adding a page break after the first Tablix (Tablix properties > insert page break after), but this only breaks the elements to the second page column, if the first Tablix happens to end in the first column.
Adding another page break before the next Tablix (Tablix properties > insert page break before) fixes it in this case, but makes the second Tablix start in the second column if the first column is empty.

Is there a way to actually force breaking to a new **page**, instead of just breaking to a new **column**?